# Operations on a Dask DataFrame fail when using snappy compression

Tags: python, pandas, dask, amazon-emr

I partitioned a large dataset into a sequence of `parquet` files using `pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet` and saved them to S3. I then read these into Dask on a cluster using `dask.read_parquet`:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_parquet(
    's3://aleksey-emr-dask/data/2019-taxi-dataset/',
    storage_options={'key': 'secret', 'secret': 'secret'},
    engine='fastparquet'
)
```

`pandas` uses `snappy` compression by default. `fastparquet` is able to work with this compression so long as you install the `python-snappy` and `snappy` packages. Since I am running on AWS EMR, and using [Dask's EMR example bootstrap script](https://yarn.dask.org/en/latest/aws-emr.html), I have installed these packages from `conda-forge` using the `--botstrap-actions` flag and the `--conda-packages` optional argument:

```
python3 -m pip list | grep snappy
python-snappy          0.5.4
```

This is enough to make `dd.read_parquet` succeed. However, certain operations fail with `KeyError: snappy`. For example, this fails:

```
passenger_counts = df.trip_distance.value_counts().compute()
```

I know this is not an error with the cluster configuration because other operations, like this one, succeed:

```
vendors = df.VendorID.value_counts().compute()
> 2.0    53516733
> 1.0    30368157
> 4.0      267080
> Name: VendorID, dtype: int64
```

Which leads to my question. Does Dask not support `snappy` compression, even if its IO engine (`fastparquet` in this case) does?

Here is the full body of the error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(self, **kwargs)
    165         dask.base.compute
    166         """
--> 167         (result,) = compute(self, traverse=False, **kwargs)
    168         return result
    169 

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dask/base.py in compute(*args, **kwargs)
    445         postcomputes.append(x.__dask_postcompute__())
    446 
--> 447     results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    448     return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])
    449 

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py in get(self, dsk, keys, restrictions, loose_restrictions, resources, sync, asynchronous, direct, retries, priority, fifo_timeout, actors, **kwargs)
   2686                     should_rejoin = False
   2687             try:
-> 2688                 results = self.gather(packed, asynchronous=asynchronous, direct=direct)
   2689             finally:
   2690                 for f in futures.values():

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py in gather(self, futures, errors, direct, asynchronous)
   1986                 direct=direct,
   1987                 local_worker=local_worker,
-> 1988                 asynchronous=asynchronous,
   1989             )
   1990 

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py in sync(self, func, asynchronous, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    831         else:
    832             return sync(
--> 833                 self.loop, func, *args, callback_timeout=callback_timeout, **kwargs
    834             )
    835 

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in sync(loop, func, callback_timeout, *args, **kwargs)
    337     if error[0]:
    338         typ, exc, tb = error[0]
--> 339         raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
    340     else:
    341         return result[0]

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils.py in f()
    321             if callback_timeout is not None:
    322                 future = asyncio.wait_for(future, callback_timeout)
--> 323             result[0] = yield future
    324         except Exception as exc:
    325             error[0] = sys.exc_info()

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/gen.py in run(self)
    733 
    734                     try:
--> 735                         value = future.result()
    736                     except Exception:
    737                         exc_info = sys.exc_info()

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py in _gather(self, futures, errors, direct, local_worker)
   1874                 else:
   1875                     self._gather_future = future
-> 1876                 response = await future
   1877 
   1878             if response["status"] == "error":

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/client.py in _gather_remote(self, direct, local_worker)
   1925 
   1926             else:  # ask scheduler to gather data for us
-> 1927                 response = await retry_operation(self.scheduler.gather, keys=keys)
   1928 
   1929         return response

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py in retry_operation(coro, operation, *args, **kwargs)
    388         delay_min=retry_delay_min,
    389         delay_max=retry_delay_max,
--> 390         operation=operation,
    391     )

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/utils_comm.py in retry(coro, count, delay_min, delay_max, jitter_fraction, retry_on_exceptions, operation)
    368                 delay *= 1 + random.random() * jitter_fraction
    369             await asyncio.sleep(delay)
--> 370     return await coro()
    371 
    372 

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py in send_recv_from_rpc(**kwargs)
    859             name, comm.name = comm.name, "ConnectionPool." + key
    860             try:
--> 861                 result = await send_recv(comm=comm, op=key, **kwargs)
    862             finally:
    863                 self.pool.reuse(self.addr, comm)

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/core.py in send_recv(comm, reply, serializers, deserializers, **kwargs)
    642         await comm.write(msg, serializers=serializers, on_error="raise")
    643         if reply:
--> 644             response = await comm.read(deserializers=deserializers)
    645         else:
    646             response = None

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/tcp.py in read(self, deserializers)
    204                     deserialize=self.deserialize,
    205                     deserializers=deserializers,
--> 206                     allow_offload=self.allow_offload,
    207                 )
    208             except EOFError:

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py in from_frames(frames, deserialize, deserializers, allow_offload)
     85         res = await offload(_from_frames)
     86     else:
---> 87         res = _from_frames()
     88 
     89     return res

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/comm/utils.py in _from_frames()
     64         try:
     65             return protocol.loads(
---> 66                 frames, deserialize=deserialize, deserializers=deserializers
     67             )
     68         except EOFError:

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/core.py in loads(frames, deserialize, deserializers)
    126             if deserialize or key in bytestrings:
    127                 if "compression" in head:
--> 128                     fs = decompress(head, fs)
    129                 fs = merge_frames(head, fs)
    130                 value = _deserialize(head, fs, deserializers=deserializers)

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/compression.py in decompress(header, frames)
    214     return [
    215         compressions[c]["decompress"](frame)
--> 216         for c, frame in zip(header["compression"], frames)
    217     ]

~/opt/miniconda3/envs/dask-local-test-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/distributed/protocol/compression.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    214     return [
    215         compressions[c]["decompress"](frame)
--> 216         for c, frame in zip(header["compression"], frames)
    217     ]

KeyError: 'snappy'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have `snappy` and `python-snappy` installed in the client environment as well, so that the worker can use the codec to turn source bytes into data.

I'm accessing the cluster from a local Jupyter notebook on my machine via SSH port forwarding, and did not have these packages installed locally. Installing them in my local env:

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge snappy python-snappy
```

Resolved the issue.